# More efficient way to update subdocuments, NodeJS and Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Thanks for reading.  I'm new and learning mongoose and trying to wrap my head around subdocument updates.  I can update sub-documents but the method I'm using doesn't seem like it would scale all that well and would be cumbersome to setup, but it does work.  I do not want to have to update field by field, ie city, state, zip, country, etc.  I would like to simply replace the fields that have been updated automatically.

```
// Sample Object
{
  addressType: 'home',
  street: '123 Easy Street',
  city: 'Somewhere',
  state: 'NA',
  zip: '90210',
  country: 'USA'
}

// Schema
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({billingProfile: [billingProfileSchema], orders: [orderSchema]}, {timestamps: true, strict: false})


// Updating item by item works, BUT doesn't scale
const billingProfile = await User.findOneAndUpdate({_id:req.user._id, "billingProfile._id":req.params.billingProfileID}, {$set: {"billingProfile.$.city" : req.body.city}}, {new:true})
```

What I logically want would be the following however it results in an error...

```
// Setting req.body equal to ".$" results in an error
const billingProfile = await User.findOneAndUpdate({_id:req.user._id, "billingProfile._id":req.params.billingProfileID}, {$set: {"billingProfile.$" : req.body}}, {new:true})
    
Updating the path 'billingProfile.$.updatedAt' would create a conflict at 'billingProfile.$'
```

The method that I would think should work, clearly does not.  I'm hoping someone can help me with a more efficient way of updating subdocuments.  Thank you :)

FYI - I'm using  `"mongoose": "^6.1.1"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of mongoose schema `{ timestamps: true }` option, which will automatically set `updatedAt` field when update happens.

One alternative way is to manage `createdAt` and `updatedAt` of billingProfileSchema manually.

Or just set `{ timestamps: false }` for billingProfileSchema

Comment: That's very interesting and clearly the solution you provided works but I'm left a bit baffled.  I would think within the findByIdAndUpdate method, the save() would handle the updateAt method but I'm missing something in Mongoose's logic.  Is there any documentation that would shed some light on this?  Thanks for your help with this :)